# Using wordpress functions outside wordpress version 4.4

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use some wordpress function in a script located in the wordpress root directory, just that some of the wordpress functions work others don't: `get_users` function works well but `wp_delete_user` doesn't.
What am I missing? PLugin is out of discussion.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-blog-header.php");
global $wpdb;
$args = array(
    'role' => 'test_taker'
);
$users = get_users( $args ); // This works
//var_dump($users);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    //var_dump($user->ID);
    wp_delete_user( $user->ID ); // This doesn't work
}
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files

Comment: @j08691 Same Error, tried added constant `WP_USE_THEMES` with trie and false as value and also tried adding wp-load.php, still the wp_ functions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution. When you get undefined function, that means you need to copy the function into the external file. For example in my case `wp_delete_user` needed to copy it from here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/